# Images that I mapped to an object won't show up when I render the image

Tags: game-engine

I'm using blender game engine and I noticed recently that when I have any object, let's use a plane for this example and I map an image to it using the UV image editor, it won't show up when I play the game. This is also when I just render an image. I set the view mode to textured and it comes up but when I render it, it doesn't, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object that is UV-unwrapped will show the UV-mapped image in texture mode in a 3d-view. If however the object hasn't had a material and texture assigned to it, the image or texture wont be rendered, as seen in first image.

[image]

Add a material to the object, then a texture to the material. Choose "image or movie" and open the image. Set Mapping to UV and choose the UV-map.

[image]