# Uv Unwrap not working

Tags: uv

After I unwrap in my current project file the texture never appears in rendered mode what could I be doing wrong? When I watch tutorials they unwrap and the texture automatically appears on the object you are working on.

Comment: Are you in *textured view* (Alt Z)? ([related](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41778/images-that-i-mapped-to-an-object-wont-show-up-when-i-render-the-image))

Comment: when I check textured view the object is black and not what I have in the uv editor... I don't know what I am doing wrong I selected the image and unwrap the object yet nothing appears in rendered view or textured view.

Comment: In blender internal you have to switch display mode from multitexture to GLSL (under shading in in 3d-view) for the texture to appear in texture view. Don't know about cycles.

Comment: Are you using Blender internal or Cycles? Can you edit your question and add images showing the UV/image editor and the material and texture setups on the properties panel?

Comment: You need to create a material, then assign a texture to it that uses the UV mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Mark out the seam on the mesh in the 3D View window.
Open a UV/Image Editor window.
Make sure the **whole** mesh is selected in the 3D view (press <kbd>A</kbd> key a couple of times if necessary).
Then select Unwrap (or press <kbd>U</kbd> while mouse is over 3D View).

You should then see the unwrapped model in the UV/Image editor window.